# "Unknown encoder: libx264" error in Debian Squeeze

Tags: ffmpeg, debian, x264

I built and installed FFMPEG as [said here](http://www.zoharbabin.com/build-and-install-ffmpeg-and-x264-on-debian-squeeze-the-dumb-guide).

But when I do this command to run the video:

```
ffmpeg -i "source.mkv" -an -b 700k -r 25 -vcodec libx264 "output.mp4"
```

I get this error:

```
unknow encoder : libx264
```

I use Debian Squeeze. How can I fix this? Please help

Thanks!!

Comment: better ask at http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 4):

your version of ffmpeg seems to have been compiled without libx264 support.
try
    $ ffmpeg -codecs
to see a list of all supported codecs.

afair (all my squeeze boxes are servers where i don't feel like installing ffmpeg onto), x264 was not part of squeeze.
the easiest way (without upgrading your system to wheezy), would be to install a more recent version from [backports](http://backports.debian.org/).

and i agree with Kuf, that this is not really a programming question, so it should go to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) or [superuser](http://superuser.com)